# Hibernate/Spring: Not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, dao

I'm developing an application using Hibernate, Spring and GWT in Java. I used reverse engineering under Hibernate (JBoss Developer Studio used) to obtain POJOs and configuration files from an existing MySQL database. It's very simple database with only two entities: Country and Citizen. They have OneToMany relationship between.

Here is the code:

app entry point:

```
...

                    Country country = new Country();
                    country.setName("NameOfCountry"+i);
                    country.setPopulation(10000);

                    Citizen ctz = new Citizen();
                    ctz.setName("John");
                    ctz.setSurname("Smith");


                    ctz.setCountry(country);
                    country.getCitizens().add(ctz);

                    service.saveCitizen(ctz, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            System.out.println("Problem saving citizen");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                            System.out.println("Citizen successfully saved");

                        }

                    });

                    service.saveCountry(country, new AsyncCallback<Boolean>(){

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                            System.out.println("Problem saving country");

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                            System.out.println("Country successfully saved");

                        }
                    });

...
```

-- service provides simple GWT-RPC call to server

Service on server:

```
@Service("componentService")
public class ComponentServiceImpl implements ComponentService{

    @Autowired
    private CountryDAO daoCnt;

    @Autowired
    private CitizenDAO daoCtz;

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public boolean saveCitizen(Citizen citizen) {
        daoCtz.saveOrUpdate(citizen);
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public boolean saveCountry(Country country) {
        daoCnt.saveOrUpdate(country);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now SpringDAOs:

CitizenDAO:

```
@Repository
public class CitizenDAO {

...
    public void saveOrUpdate(Citizen citizen){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(citizen);
    }
...
```

CountryDAO:

```
@Repository
public class CountryDAO {

...
    public void saveOrUpdate(Country country){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(country);
    }
...
```

Finally

Citizen.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sk.jakub.mod.shared.model.Citizen" table="citizen" catalog="modeldb">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="country" class="sk.jakub.mod.shared.model.Country" fetch="select">
            <column name="Country_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="surname" type="string">
            <column name="surname" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Country.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="sk.jakub.mod.shared.model.Country" table="country" catalog="modeldb">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="population" type="int">
            <column name="population" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="citizens" table="citizen" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="Country_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="sk.jakub.mod.shared.model.Citizen" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I havent listed Citizen.java and Country.java because they are only basic POJOs (if necessary I'll provide them).

When I launch my app and I want to save my data into database I obtain following error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: sk.jakub.mod.shared.model.Citizen.country
```

I can't figure out where is the problem. I was trying also instead of saveOrUpdate method, persist method. Or also to change the order of saving into database. Nothing seemed to work.

Thank you very much for help :) If needed, I can post more code from my application.

EDIT:
code for Citizen.java:

```
public class Citizen implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3102863479088406293L;
    private Integer id;
    private Country country;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public Citizen() {
    }

    public Citizen(Country country, String name, String surname) {
        this.country = country;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Stat getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return this.surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Country.java:

```
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4085805854508658303L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private int population;
    private Set<Citizen> citizens = new HashSet<Citizen>();

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(String name, int population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public Country(String name, int population, Set<Citizen> citizens) {
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.citizens = citizens;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return this.population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public Set<Citizen> getCitizens() {
        return this.citizens;
    }

    public void setCitizens(Set<Citizen> citizens) {
        this.citizens = citizens;
    }
}
```

Furthermore, I've checked the database manually and Country is saved but citizen is not.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to save a Citizen POJO that has a null Country object.  Can you include the code for Country and Citizen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing that you are creating a Citizen before you create a country. Also both the service calls should be in same transaction for the whole operation to be atomic. The COUNTRY_ID seems to be a self generated id i believe. So once you create the country you can attach that to a citizen but you call stack shows you are creating a citizen which has a Country object which doesnt have an id. This is just my guess. You can try putting both the calls under same transaction and also try creating a Country and attach that country instance to the Citizen.

Comment: thank you very much. The problem was in the transaction. First save to database went in one transaction, the other save went in another. And there was the problem. So, if tehre are dependencies such this one, they have to go in one transaction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have implemented the equals, hashcode and compareTo (if applicable) methods properly. I have recently faced this problem and resolved it by proper implemetation of these.